# How do I stop my div from escaping the browser window like this?

Tags: css

[image]

I'm making a plotted chart in react.js and have a tooltip div that is created from the absolute position of the plot point x/y coordinates. When the popover text is too long it collides with the browser only on the left side, for whatever reason it wraps properly on the right side as seen in the photo. How do I get the wrapping behavior to occur on both sides?

```
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px;
    font: 12px sans-serif;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    pointer-events: none;
    min-width: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code here, so we can correct it

Comment: you can wrap the text by  giving your tooltip a particular width. I hope this solve your problem!!

Comment: Sorry, I've added the current styling I have on it. When I create the element I also specify it's left/top position

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the code, thus I cannot code it, but I assume you would do a @media query on some particular screen width and change the `.tooltip` css properties - the width for example.

Hope it helps!